# how to display both image in same activity while pressing back in android?

Tags: android, button, imageview, sharedpreferences

In `MainActivity` I have three buttons: `Add table`, `Add chair`, `Reset`. For both buttons click adds image in second activity. When I click `Add table` it adds table image, but when I go back for adding chair, table image is not there. I want both images persisted after going back. `Reset` button clears all images in second activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        }
        public  void addtable(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Second.class);
            i.putExtra("table",1);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        public  void addchair(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Second.class);
            i.putExtra("chair",1);
            startActivity(i);
        }

}
```

Second activity:

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.second_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        /*toolbar.setNavigationIcon((R.drawable.back_arrow));

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });*/


        LinearLayoutCompat hall = (LinearLayoutCompat) findViewById(R.id.hall_layout);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int x = i.getIntExtra("table",0);
        int y = i.getIntExtra("chair",0);
        if (x==1) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.table);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200,200));
            iv.setMaxHeight(120);
            iv.setMaxWidth(120);
            hall.addView(iv);
        }
        if (y==1) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.chair);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200,200));
            iv.setMaxHeight(120);
            iv.setMaxWidth(120);
            hall.addView(iv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andiroot.restaurantbook.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff1e8622"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addtbl"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:text="Add Table"
            android:onClick="addtable"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addchairs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="addchair"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Add Chair"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_addtbl"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_addtbl" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_addchairs"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_addchairs"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
            android:text="Reset" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/hall_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andiroot.restaurantbook.Second">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/second_toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff1e8622"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: back pressed override method for bressing back

Comment: navigation back  and back press override method include the code finsish();

Comment: you have any example ?

Comment: @user3578882 I would prefer a different logic other than this. If you use a array of string you can maintain your code easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<String> mSelecetdItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final String SELECETD_ITEMS = "SELECETD_ITEMS";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     }


    public  void addtable(View v){
        this.mSelecetdItems.add("table");
        showSecondActivity();
    }
    public  void addchair(View v){
        this.mSelecetdItems.add("chair");
        showSecondActivity();
    }


    private void showSecondActivity()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Second.class);
        i.putStringArrayListExtra(SELECETD_ITEMS,this.mSelecetdItems);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList(SELECETD_ITEMS , mSelecetdItems);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        this.mSelecetdItems = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(SELECETD_ITEMS);
    }


}
```

and second.class will be like this ,

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.second_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        /*toolbar.setNavigationIcon((R.drawable.back_arrow));

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });*/


        LinearLayoutCompat hall = (LinearLayoutCompat) findViewById(R.id.hall_layout);
        Intent i = getIntent();


        ArrayList<String> selecetdItems = i.getStringArrayListExtra(MainActivity.SELECETD_ITEMS);
        for (String selecetdItem : selecetdItems) {
            if (selecetdItem.equals("table")) {
                addImageView(R.drawable.table, hall);
            } else if (selecetdItem.equals("chair")) {
                addImageView(R.drawable.chair, hall);
            }
        }


    }

    private void addImageView(int imageRes, LinearLayoutCompat hall) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageResource(imageRes);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        iv.setMaxHeight(120);
        iv.setMaxWidth(120);
        hall.addView(iv);
    }


}
```

Comment: although it's working with hardware back button not on screen back button.I have to create functionality on screen back button which I have enabled in Toolbar

Comment: @user3578882 What is happening now with screen back button?

Comment: if i clicked table add button than table image shows and when I press screen back button and try to add chair only chair image shows and how can I change size of each table and chair particularly ?

Comment: @user3578882 What are you doing in that screen back button ? If you share the code i can check

Comment: I have enabled back button in toolbar second activity

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.second_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


and in manifest

  <activity android:name=".Second">



            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />




        </activity>

Comment: @user3578882 and is it going back to your MainActivity?

Comment: @user3578882 can you change like this  private static ArrayList<String> mSelecetdItems = new ArrayList<>();  to static ln MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what you want to do, you could just store x and y in a class with 2 static int. In the Second class you display the image in function of the result of the static int.

Button reset just have to put the 2 static int to 0.